# IOS Universal Framework (kstenerud)

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

I've created three "Real" frameworks that work fine in debug/release xcode 4.2 builds.  When I try to build an Archive I get the error "clang++ failed with exit code 1".

If I remove the "Real" frameworks (References, comment code) from the project I can get it to Archive.  I've also got some self built static libraries in the project that work fine when Archiving.

Any ideas?